# Using mmap to reverse a text file in place -- getting bus error

Tags: c, mmap

I thought i had it figured out but i'm getting a bus error. All it has to do is take some text file, use mmap and then reverse the contents without a temp file. What i did was map it, and then erase the file and write it from memory by starting at the end of the mmap pointer. This worked when I did it with cout, but for some reason doing it to a file i get the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/io.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>


main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  unsigned char *f, *g;
  int size;
  struct stat s;
  const char * file_name = argv[1];
  int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

  int status = fstat(fd, &s);
  size = s.st_size;
  int i;
  f = (char *) mmap (0, size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
  //g = (char *) mmap (0, size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);

  for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    char c;

    c = f[i];
    putchar(c);
  }
  //ABOVE THIS WORKS


  // int z = 0;
  //while(f[z] != NULL) {
  //z++;
    // printf("%d", z);
  // }
  int x;
  int y = 0;
  close(fd);

  FILE *f1;

  f1 = fopen(argv[1], "w+");

  for(x = size - 1; x >= 0; x--)
    {
      char c;

      c = f[x];
      fputc(c, f1);
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you fopened the file with `w`, you truncated the file to 0 length.  The mmap man page says that:

> The effect of changing the size of the underlying file of a mapping on the pages that correspond to added or removed regions of the file is unspecified.

Anyways, it seems to me that you should call `mmap` with `PROT_WRITE` also, so that you can just reverse the array `f` in memory.  Then you don't have to open the file again.  Make sure to use MMAP_SHARED, and to also call munmap() after you are finished modifying the shared memory.  You need MMAP_SHARED because with MMAP_PRIVATE:

> Updates to the mapping are not visible to other processes mapping the same file, and are not carried through to the underlying file.

You should call munmap() because:

> The file may not actually be updated until msync(2) or munmap() is called.

If you exit the program without calling munmap(), the memory will automatically be unmapped for you.  But it's a good habit to close/free/unmap things yourself instead of just exiting.

(Edit: Thanks Adam Rosenfield and EOF for the corrections to my original answer.)

Comment: Furthermore, the [`mmap(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) documentation says that when `MAP_PRIVATE` is used, "It is unspecified whether changes made to the file after the mmap() call are visible in the mapped region.".  So even if `fd` wasn't closed, the moment the other `fopen()` call is made, the mmap'ed contents become indeterminate.

Comment: well, the only reason i was doing the second open was to empty the contents of the file first, instead of just adding onto what i already had.

Comment: Once you mmap the file with write permission, changing the mapped memory is the same as changing the file.  So you don't need to clear the file.  Or if you wanted to clear it, just memset your mapped memory to 0.

Comment: alright so when you posted last about changing the mapped area is the same as changing the file, i went back and removed quite a bit because that made it simpler. now i don't understand why it isn't working, the debugging output statement i use shows it in reverse yet the file stays in the normal state. code here http://ideone.com/nIwfgs

Comment: Use MAP_SHARED instead of MAP_PRIVATE.  According to the man page for mmap, if you use MAP_PRIVATE, any changes you make won't get written to the file. Also, I think its a good idea to call munmap when you are done with the mapped memory.

Comment: `man munmap`:"[...]On the other hand, closing the file descriptor does not unmap the region."

Comment: Thanks EOF.  I updated my answer to correct my mistakes.